# error al momento de crear una base de datos en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

buenas compañeros del grupo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que sucede es que voy  a hacer las practicas en PostgreSQL y me sale el siguiente error , algun experto en postgresql me puede ayudar con ese problema ,por favor ...

Comment: Has cambiado recientemente de version de pgadmin? tienes alguna otra versión de postgres instalada además de la que muestras en la imagen? Tienes algun otro gestor aparte de postgres en tu computador (ejemplo oracle o mysql)?

Comment: tengo instalada workbeanch y xampp , tambien tengo instalada la version 10 de pgadmin ,hay algun problema con eso ??

Comment: Tienes instalado postgreSQL en la máquina ? Esta el servicio ejecutándose ?

Comment: Pgadmin es el gestor no el motor de base de datos tienes que instalarlo

Comment: si se refiere que la tengo instalada en el disco local c , siii

Comment: Puede ser muchas cosas. Si tienes dos postgresql en la maquina puede que exista conflicto entre ambos por uso del mismo puerto, puede pasar que tengas el servicio de postgres sin iniciar o detenido de allí la pregunta de @JackNavaRow sobre si el servicio se está ejecutando. Puede también que instalaste postgres, lo desinstalaste incorrectamente y luego instalaste nuevamente lo cual muchas veces también ocasiona problemas

Answer (score 0):

Puede suceder por 2 problemas diferentes.

Te estas intentando conectar ha un servidor externo y tenias la session de la cuenta activa y ha pasado un intervalo X de tiempo y ha expirado el token y hace falta loguearse de nuevo.

O estas intentando conectar con el servidor por primera vez o haz cambiado algo referente a la configuración de red.
Si es este caso deberias configurar el fichero **"postgresql.conf"** y añadir tú Ip publica , en el apartado "listen_addresses" si necesitas añadir varias Ip's 
es

listen_addresses = 'XXX.XX..','XXX.XX..'

En caso de estar comentado la linea descomentar-la

En Ubuntu, los archivo se encuentran en

```
/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/.
```

Fuente: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532399/unable-to-connect-to-server-for-postgres)

Para configurarlo desde pgAdmin: [Aquí](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61193/how-to-edit-postgresql-conf-with-pgadmin)